# Change result from operation if equal to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created this query, but sometimes this part `(CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, od.insstart, NOW()) / od.term)` **returns 0**, So I want to check result from this part and if it's equal to 0, to change it to 1, **before** compare it with second part `= (SELECT COUNT(id)` is there a way to do this ?

```
SELECT id FROM od where pol = '123' AND (CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, od.insstart, NOW()) / od.term) = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM od as tt WHERE tt.policyNumber = '123'))
```

If result from `(CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, od.insstart, NOW()) / od.term)` is equal to 0 **->** change it to 1 and then compare with second part which is `(SELECT COUNT(id)`

Comment: `GREATEST( CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, od.insstart, NOW()) / od.term), 1 )`

Comment: @Akina Thank you, will you post this as answer or I should delete the question ?

Comment: As far as I understand your query, you try to get the number of complete months for an insurance contract, but within the first month you only get 0 instead of 1. Depending on your requirements, what if the duration is a bit more then a month: Do you get an integer or an float value from timestampdiff (with month clause)? As far the samples on mysql pages show, for month there are integers.... so if you have 33 days, you will still get 1 as answer, because ceiling will not round up an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GREATEST() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

```
GREATEST( CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, od.insstart, NOW()) / od.term), 1 )
```